# Picking colors through Interface Builder

Tags: iphone

We have a color defined in a constants.h file like so

```
#define CUSTOM_ORANGE [UIColor colorWithRed:173/255. green:22/255. blue:35/255. alpha:1.0]
```

When I create a UIView in IB and want to change the color to this color, I open up the RGB sliders and set it to those same values of 173, 22, 35 and the color is not the same.  Why is that and how can I get my custom color in IB?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple add-ons I like this one [Developer-Color Picker](http://panic.com/~wade/picker/)

Or you can use Hex Color which is really easy.  Read this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805313/413594)