# What is a good way to implement [UIColor colorWithRGBString:@"#3A6FFC"]?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I probably would use `scanf` and then `&` with `0xff, 0xff00, 0xff0000` and shift them to get the 3 values for RGB and then call `[UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha: 1]`.  Is there a better or easy way to implement it?

The `#` in front should be optional in the string, and it shouldn't be case sensitive so `3a6ffc` should work as well as `#3A6FFC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert the nsstring to hex values, and then get the R, G and B from the hex
The following stackoverflow answer is what you are looking for

[How to convert HEX RGB color codes to UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805177/how-to-convert-hex-rgb-color-codes-to-uicolor)