# Convert a string like "ff0000" to hexadecimal number in objective c

Tags: objective-c, parsing, color-picker, hex, color-codes

I need to convert a string input from UI to a hexadecimal number in objective c. The string is an HTML color code like "ff0000" (the '#' will be dealt with diagrammatically) and it is supposed to be converted to the number ff0000 in order to provide color selection. Alternatively, is there a color chooser in objective c? didn't find one in the xib objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert HEX RGB color codes to UIColor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805177/how-to-convert-hex-rgb-color-codes-to-uicolor)

Comment: Fis'Zen, the link you provide deals with converting hexadecimal to decimal, it is not what I asked. @rob, you are right, but since I did search for an answer and couldn't find that post (it uses a different way to describe the problem) it might be better to leave both intact, if only so people can find my question and see your link, maybe?

Comment: Note that there is really no such thing as a hexadecimal number, that is just a display type. So the question might be better as: Convert a hexadecimal string representation to an integer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Objective C parse hex string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411)

```
unsigned result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"ff0000"];
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
```

or using "c":

```
uint32_t value;
NSString *stringValue = @"ff0000";
const char *string = [stringValue cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
sscanf(string, "%x" , &value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below line for conversion. Its just one line code:

```
NSString *hexString = @"01FFFFAB";
length = (UInt64)strtoull([sizeLine UTF8String], NULL, 16);
NSLog(@"The required Length is %d", length);
```

Happy Coding!!!