# integer value from NSString with multiple zeros

Tags: nsstring, integer, return-value, zero

I'm mostly sending UIColor hex code threw web, and when retrieving it I only get one digit for some numbers. So if I send 000 when retrieving it, its only 0. How can I get whole value and not remove any digit ? Same thing will happen for example with 090.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the values as NSString instead of integer or NSNumber, because they will not keep the leading zeros.

You can find a lot of functions around to convert from hex string to UIColor: [How to convert HEX RGB color codes to UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805177/how-to-convert-hex-rgb-color-codes-to-uicolor)