# How can I provide colour to button background in accordance with Hashtag Value or Hex Colour Code , like it used to be in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift

Every article up on the internet suggests me using RGB. But, I want to use Apple's green colour palette and I am futile in the venture. I know it's hashtag value but, unable to render it on the simulator due to the fact that I don't know the appropriate method to use it inside the view controller file.

Since, I have been able to render the desired colour by using **Color Literal** but, there is never an ending to learning. And, I want to know the coding way of it!

**self.buttonStart.backgroundColor = UIColor(?)**

**? :** *What should I put inside the aforementioned parentheses to accomplish my task. Any suggestions?*

Comment: Your question is unclear. Define "hashtag value". Did you mean Hex value, like we it's used to be set with RGB(A)?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805177/how-to-convert-hex-rgb-color-codes-to-uicolor

Comment: @Larme I believe I have rectified the doubt. Edited the title of problem and I hope you get it now! Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following extension.

```
extension UIColor {
    var applicationButtonColor : UIColor {
        return UIColor(hex: "52C2FF")
    }
    
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0
        
        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
        
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
        
        let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbValue & 0xff
        
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
            green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
            blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
        )
    }
}
```

And you can use it in your class like:

```
self.buttonStart.backgroundColor = UIColor().applicationButtonColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a `UIColor` from a hex string value like following -

```
public extension UIColor {
    
    static func from(hexString: String) -> UIColor {
        var cleanString = hexString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
        
        if cleanString.count == 3 {
            var updatedString = ""
            cleanString.forEach({ updatedString.append("\($0)\($0)") })
            cleanString = updatedString
        }
        
        if cleanString.count == 6 {
            cleanString = cleanString.appending("ff")
        }
        
        var baseValue: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cleanString).scanHexInt32(&baseValue)
        
        let red = CGFloat((baseValue >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0
        let green = CGFloat((baseValue >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((baseValue >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0
        let alpha = CGFloat((baseValue >> 0) & 0xFF)/255.0
        
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    
}
```

Now from your code, you can call it like following -

```
self.buttonStart.backgroundColor = UIColor.from(hexString: "#AABBCC")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this two public extensions in your code:

```
private extension Int {
    func duplicate4bits() -> Int {
        return (self << 4) + self
    }
}

public extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        self.init(hexString: hexString, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
    private convenience init?(hex3: Int, alpha: Float) {
        self.init(red:   CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0xF00) >> 8).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0x0F0) >> 4).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
                  blue:  CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0x00F) >> 0).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
                  alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
    
    private convenience init?(hex6: Int, alpha: Float) {
        self.init(red:   CGFloat( (hex6 & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat( (hex6 & 0x00FF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
                  blue:  CGFloat( (hex6 & 0x0000FF) >> 0 ) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
    
    private convenience init?(hex8: Int, alpha: Float) {
        self.init(red:   CGFloat( (hex8 & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat( (hex8 & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
                  blue:  CGFloat( (hex8 & 0xFF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
                  alpha: CGFloat((Int(alpha) & 0xFF) >> 0 ) / 255.0)
    }
    
    public convenience init?(hexString: String, alpha: Float) {
        var hex = hexString
        
        // Check for hash and remove the hash
        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            hex = String(hex[hex.index(after: hex.startIndex)...])
        }
        
        guard let hexVal = Int(hex, radix: 16) else {
            self.init()
            return nil
        }
        
        switch hex.count {
        case 3:
            self.init(hex3: hexVal, alpha: alpha)
        case 6:
            self.init(hex6: hexVal, alpha: alpha)
        case 8:
            self.init(hex8: hexVal, alpha: alpha)
        default:
            self.init()
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    public convenience init?(hex: Int) {
        self.init(hex: hex, alpha: 1.0)
    }
   
    public convenience init?(hex: Int, alpha: Float) {
        if (0x000000 ... 0xFFFFFF) ~= hex {
            self.init(hex6: hex, alpha: alpha)
        } else {
            self.init()
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now from your code you can call it like here:

```
self.buttonStart.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#4d4d4d")
```